# Area of a Unit Disk

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

> True or false?
>   A unit disk’s area can be evaluated using the Cartesian coordinate system area formula.

I was given this question to answer, and I have no idea what it is asking. What is a unit disk? Assuming it is like the unit circle, can't if find the area with $\pi r^2$? Is this the cartesian system or is it polar?

**EDIT**

I've now seen the correct answer with the explanation. The answer is True, and this is the reason provided.

[image]

Any enlightenment?

Comment: The real question to me is, what is the "Cartesian coordinate system area formula"?

Comment: Since I do not know of any formula called the "Cartesian coordinate system area formula", I am going to go with false.

Comment: Yeah, the question seems weird. Is this the real question?

Comment: A disk is the region enclosed by a circle.  A circle is one-dimensional, and a disk is two-dimensional.

Comment: To piggyback off @saulspatz comment: the unit disk is such a disk where the radius is one unit.

Comment: @Mr.N Ya, I copied and pasted it. So, it's a weird question and it's doesn't mean I don't know any of the information

Comment: @Burt, okay. I'm with InsterstellarProbe then.

Comment: $$4 \int\limits_{x=0}^1 \sqrt{1 - x^2}\ dx$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question intends the Cartesian coordinate system area formula to be 
$$Area=\int y\; \text{d}x$$
where the limits are chosen according to the region you want to find the area of.  I guess the point is that you can find a function to describe the (upper half of the) disk using Cartesian coordinates in $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and can integrate that from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: Why does it need to be negative one to one? Why can't it be zero to one?

Comment: It is $-1$ to $1$ if you want to compute the upper half and double it as the answer states.  You can also do $0$ to $1$ and multiply by $4$ because you only got a quarter.  Either way you are using the symmetry of the disk.  You could even do $-1$ to $1$ twice, once for the part above the axis and once for the part below.